# Lectcode 100. Same Tree solution understanding

Tags: recursion

Q: Given the roots of two binary trees p and q, write a function to check if they are the same or not.
solution:

```
class Solution {
public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
// p and q are both null
if (p == null && q == null) return true;
// one of p and q is null
if (q == null || p == null) return false;
if (p.val != q.val) return false;
return isSameTree(p.right, q.right) &&
        isSameTree(p.left, q.left);
 }
}
```

I am confused about the "return isSameTree(p.right, q.right) &&
isSameTree(p.left, q.left);" what is the meaning of it, and why there is no condition like "else" before it ??? what it return finally ?

Comment: There are three ways to exit the function before you get there: each of those first three return statements could have an else if after them but there is no point because an else is designed to keep code from being executed if the then part is true and the return statement already does that.  For example: `if (x) { return true; } else { return false; }` does exactly the same thing as `if (x) { return true; }` followed separately by `return false;`

Comment: Welcome to SO! `else if` and `else` are meaningless if the branches all have unconditional return statements in them as is the case here. After passing the 3 precondition/base case checks, the final line checks that both subtrees are the same and returns that result to the caller.